# How to assign InputBox value to Header?

Tags: excel, vba

At the moment my code is causing [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) to crash.

```
Sub headerDate()
Dim iReply As String

iReply = Application.InputBox("What is the input? ")
With ActiveSheet.pageSetup
    .CenterHeader = ""
    .RightHeader = _
    "                        Doc. No.: " & str(iReply) & Chr(10) & "Version: 2.3 (Modification f)" & Chr(10) & "Valid as of: 12/31/2012  "
End With
Application.PrintCommunication = True
Range("BI2").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change Str to Cstr:

```
"Doc. No.: " & CStr(iReply) & Chr(10) & "Version: 2.3 (Modification f)" & Chr(10) ...
```